# R Error Message: Removed 3088 rows containing missing values (geom_point)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and trying to generate a graph.  I was able to do it before using the same code with no issue.  Now my x-axis data won't display and I get the missing data error.  My code is:

```
ass2_graph1<-ggplot(data=pd,aes(y=homeown_rate,x=homeown_rate_rank,color="Actual"))
ass2_graph1<-ass2_graph1+geom_point(alpha=.5,size=.5)
ass2_graph1<-ass2_graph1+geom_point(aes(y=homeown_rate_mean,x=homeown_rate_rank,color="The Predictor: The Unconditional Mean"),size=.5)
ass2_graph1<-ass2_graph1+xlab("Rank of Home Ownership Rates")+ylab("Home Ownership Rates")
ass2_graph1<-ass2_graph1+scale_color_manual(name="Type",values=c("Actual Mean"="black","The Predictor: The Unconditional Mean"="green")                   )
ass2_graph1<-ass2_graph1+theme(legend.position="bottom")

ass2_graph1
```

See below: I was able to print another graph using the same values for the x-axis.  I only changed the y.   What could I have done wrong in the code in my original post?

ass2_graph1<-ggplot(data=pd,aes(x=homeown_rate_rank,         y=homeown_rate,text=county))

Comment: Could you provide more information about your dataset? Otherwise it's quite hard to figure out a solution for your problem. Simply type `dput(NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASET)` into the console and paste the output as code into your question. As your dataset is probably large, it is best to give just a snippet of your data, e.g. for the first 20 rows `dput(NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASET[1:20, ])` will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. Here's the output:

Comment: My apologies.  Here's the output:> dput(pd[1:20,])
structure(list(fips = c("01001", "01003", "01005", "01007", "01009", 
"01011", "01013", "01015", "01017", "01019", "01021", "01023", 
"01025", "01027", "01029", "01031", "01033", "01035", "01037", 
"01039"), pop2013 = c(55246L, 195540L, 27076L, 22512L, 57872L, 
10639L, 20265L, 116736L, 34162L, 26203L, 43951L, 13426L, 25207L, 
13486L, 14994L, 50938L, 54520L, 12887L, 10898L, 37886L),

Comment: Even with the 1st 20 rows, there were too many characters. Here's what came next in the output:

Comment: popchange_pc = c(1.2, 7.3, -1.4, -1.8, 
1, -2.5, -3.3, -1.5, 0, 0.8, 0.7, -3.1, -2.4, -3.2, 0.1, 2, 0.2, 
-2.6, -5.6, 0.3), pop2010 = c(54571L, 182265L, 27457L, 22915L, 
57322L, 10914L, 20947L, 118572L, 34215L, 25989L, 43643L, 13859L, 
25833L, 13932L, 14972L, 49948L, 54428L, 13228L, 11539L, 37765L
), popu5 = c(6.1, 5.7, 5.8, 5.3, 6.1, 6.3, 6.1, 5.8, 5.9, 4.8, 
6.5, 5, 5.5, 5.4, 5.5, 6.3, 5.7, 5.5, 4.6, 5.9), popu18 = c(25.4, 
22.4, 21.1, 21.3, 23.8, 21, 23.3, 22.2, 21.4, 20.7, 24.2, 21, 
23, 21.6, 22.6, 23.7, 21.7, 21.9, 18.9, 22.1),

Comment: There are 3,088 observations of 55 variables.  So, I am not sure of the most efficient way to send you the file contents.

Comment: Just by looking at your code: the global `aes()` seems to be the same as the geom_point specific `aes()`. Any reason why you specify the same relation twice? In any case, I would take a closer look at your x variable and especially possible NAs in there.

Comment: Okay. Best is to put only the variables needed for the plot inside the data snippet, e.g. your plot uses only `homeown_rate`, `homeown_rate_rank` and `homeown_rate_mean`, e.g. dput(NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASET[1:20, c("homeown_rate", "homeown_rate_rank" and "homeown_rate_mean")]). Also. Check your code on the simple dataset and check wether it reproduces the error. Finally. Don't put the data in a comment. Put it in the question using edit.

Comment: To HeiN3r, Not sure why my professor used aes() twice.  I am very new to R.  No real explanation given for that.